# Unable to uninstall zurb-foundation

Tags: sass, bundler, zurb-foundation, padrino

I installed zurb-foundation and sass using the steps on their [getting started page](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html) e.g.

```
[sudo] gem install compass
cd path/to/where-you-want-your-project
run compass create <project-name> -r zurb-foundation --using foundation
```

But now I would like to revert back to bootstrap but I am unable to get rid of zurb-foundation from my Padrino project. Even after running `gem uninstall zurb-foundation` and checking every file in the project for a reference to "zurb" or "foundation" bundler reminds me that zurb is missing and every time I run `bundle install` it adds it to the project.

What is the best way to remove zurb-foundation from my Padrino app? Thanks

My Gemfile is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Distribute your app as a gem
# gemspec

# Server requirements
# gem 'thin' # or mongrel
# gem 'trinidad', :platform => 'jruby'

# Optional JSON codec (faster performance)
# gem 'oj'

# Project requirements
gem 'rake'

# Component requirements
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'sass'
gem 'haml'
gem 'activerecord', '>= 3.1', :require => 'active_record'
gem 'mysql2' 
gem 'json' 
gem 'annotate'
gem 'compass'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.1.2'
# gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter'

# Test requirements
gem 'shoulda', :group => 'test'
gem 'rack-test', :require => 'rack/test', :group => 'test'

# Padrino Stable Gem
gem 'padrino', '~> 0.11.1'

#rabl needs to be after padrino
gem 'rabl'

# Or Padrino Edge
# gem 'padrino', :github => 'padrino/padrino-framework'

# Or Individual Gems
# %w(core gen helpers cache mailer admin).each do |g|
#   gem 'padrino-' + g, '0.11.1'
# end
```

Comment: Does your config.rb still reference foundation?

Comment: Sorry I think I was being my own worst enemy. I switched consoles from Git bash to Powershell and it seems to be removed now.